# Having REGEX trouble excluding matches of substring in the middle of a larger string

Tags: regex

I have been trying a lot of combinations, using Regex101.com, to define a REGEX string that will find a multi character DNS TLD string that is located within the midst of a larger line of text. The TLD can have several different characters after it that would signify the end of the larger string OR it could have more characters after it which negates the match.

For example, TLD of .co is for Colombia, .ne is for Niger and .pro is a specialty TLD so I want it to match the following

```
 also works - somethingelse.co 
 jhg.ne)
 uiy.co>
 otherthing.ne> kjh
 another thing.co) and this matches
 speciality.edu.pro.
```

To do that, I have the REGEX string that does the above matches:
[`\b(\.ne|\.me|\.co|\.au|\.th|\.pro)( |>|\.|\>\)?)?`](https://regex101.com/r/Yhpagw/1)

The problem I have at this time is I can not figure out how to exclude matches against something like:

```
  Received: from dovdir4-ch2h-01o.email.comcast.net ([96.102.167.135])
by dovback4-ch2h-07o.email.comcast.net with LMTP
```

I have tried adding a 'not in range' option such as [^a-z0-9-] (all letters and numbers as well as '-') to the REGEX string and it fails to exclude matches such as '.comcast' and '.net'.

What would be the addition to the REGEX string to exclude cases where there is more characters in the DNS name other than the match to the TLDs I defined within the REGEX string PLUS the acceptable termination characters?

My thanks for your help on this!

Paul

Comment: Replace that last group with `\b`: [`\b(\.(?:ne|me|co|au|th|pro))\b`](https://regex101.com/r/Yhpagw/2).

Comment: InSync - My thanks for the education about using \b at the end of my REGEX string. I have been thinking that having it at the front also covered the end! Your suggestion gets me to what I need.